# Problems with database connection - SharePoint 2010 test environment

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-server, database-connection

we made a copy of our current SP 2010 environment to run as a Mockup in a separated network area. (we had this running before, but needed an upgrade to get a similar status as the productive farm). The duplication of the domain controllers, database and application server went well, the CA is running as expected. But the frontend server didn't get a connection to the database. Error in all web applications:

"Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [InvalidOperationException: The farm is unavailable.]
>       Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPSecurityTokenServiceManager.get_Local()
>   +24815036
>       Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPTokenCache..ctor() +34  (...)"

I tried running the configuration wizard, there I got the error message

> "Failed to detect if the server is joined to a server farm. ..."

I chose to disconnect the server from the farm and try to reconnect it (which was maybe not a good idea?), but it doesn't find the database so a connection is not possible. The database server is running and available.

Any ideas? I can rollback to the status before starting the Config Wizard if necessary.

Many thanks for your help in advance. Let me know if I should post the error message more detailed.

Best regards 
Sibylla

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally we recreated the full test environment which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something has changed in the way you need to connect to your database-server during your copy-operation.

- Which database connection string do you use to reconnect your server
  to the configuration database?
- Look for a mismatching SQL-Alias in C:\windows\system32\cliconfg.exe -> Alias

Comment: Thanks for this reply. It looks like something went wrong while creating the copy of the server, we are currently renewing the environment. I will keep this post updated.